# ASP.NET Save Image in ashx handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have a simple handler (ASHX) which receives a base 64 encoded image and I want to save that image.

Here is the code:

```
 Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest

    Dim imageInfo = context.Request("imgData")
    Dim imageData As String() = imageInfo.Split(",")

    ' check that there are two parts; ie the header and the string data.
    If imageData.Length < 2 Then
        context.Response.Write("error")
        Return
    End If

    ' Example of imageInfo
    ' data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAE...

    Dim imageType As String = imageData(0)
    Dim imageString As String = imageData(1)

    If imageType <> "data:image/png;base64" Then
        context.Response.Write("error")
        Return
    End If

    imageString = imageString.Replace(" ", "+")
    Dim bytes As Byte()
    bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imageString)

    Dim image As System.Drawing.Image

    Using ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(bytes)
        image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms)
    End Using
    image.Save("test", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)

End Sub
```

However, I get the following error:

> An exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException' occurred in
>   System.Drawing.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: A generic error occurred in GDI+

I know the image data is good as it works in the php version. I am trying to convert the PHP to ASP.NET.

```
/*get file name and image data from POST*/
$filename = $_POST['filename'];
$data = $_POST['imgdata'];

list( $type, $data ) = explode( ';', $data );
list( $base, $data ) = explode( ',', $data );

/*check that image data is base64 of png*/
if ( $type === 'data:image/png' && $base === 'base64') {
    $data = base64_decode( $data );
    file_put_contents( '../pathtosave/' . $filename, $data );
    echo 'saved';
} else {
    echo 'error';
}
```

Inspecting the image in the debugger, it appears to okay. It correctly gets the height and width of the image.

Can anyone see where the error may be?

Comment: Does the exception stacktrace give you a line number?

Comment: Just a guess: try to save the image inside the `using` statement, as the original stream probably would be disposed and the data, lost

Comment: You can't read the image into a string.  You must read it into a byte array using UTF8 encoding.  Use a stream class with UTF8.Encoding.

Comment: @RubensFarias I tried this but it didn't work unfortunately. Thanks for the suggestion, though, I thought it would work.

Comment: @jdweng Apologies, I am unsure what you are saying. I am taking the base64 encoded string and converting it to a byte array. The error occurs on the line "image.Save..."

Comment: Can you edit your question and add your test base64 string?

Comment: Dim imageData As String() = imageInfo.Split(",") Dim imageType As String = imageData(0)
    Dim imageString As String = imageData(1).  YOu can't take binary data from a file, put into string, and then back to bytes.  Once it is in a string it is corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

I am so embarrassed. The issue was that "test" is not a correct file path. I am testing this on my local machine and as soon as I used the full path, this worked straight away.